# Docker build command with --tag unable to tag images

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have trying to build a Docker image using a Dockerfile available locally.

```
docker build -t newimage .
```

I have used this command multiple times earlier too, but somehow its not working currently and i am stuck finding the reason for it.

I will be really helpful if someone can help me with a possible solution or a possible area to look for an issue.

i already had a look over other posts that could have been related for example :
[Docker build tag repository name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815524/docker-build-tag-repository-name)

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: No error message. When i run `docker images` , there is not image with such tag, instead i have an image tagged `<none>`

Comment: Then it seems you already built an image with the same tag, but a different `Dockerfile` (or made changes to it). Docker does not delete the container, it only removes the tag, resulting in `<none>`.

Comment: I just checked it. I tried clearing/removing all the images. Then i ran `docker build -t newimage .` command again , now only one image is available on running  `docker images` and that is tagged with `<none>`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Okay! I found out the reason for issue.

**DOCKER BUILD PROCESS**

When we build a docker image, while creating an image, several other intermediate images are generated in the process. We never see them in `docker images` because with the generation of next intermediate image the earlier image is removed. And in the end we have only one which is the final image.

The tag we provide using `-t` or `--tag` is for the final build, and obviously no intermediate container is tagged with the same.

**ISSUE EXPLANATION**

When we try to build a docker image with Dockerfile sometimes the process is not successfully completed with a similar message like `Successfully built image with IMAGEID`

So it is so obvious that the build which has failed will not be listed in `docker images`

Now, the image with tag `<none>` is some other image (intermediate). This creates a confusion that the image exists but without a tag, but the image is actually not what the final build should be, hence not tagged.

Comment: There should have been an error message saying that the build was not successful. Did you not see that?

Comment: No there was no such message! I made a typo in a command , so there was a log saying the command returned non-zero output , `/bin/sh: 1: s: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c s' returned a non-zero code: 127
` something like this ..  but there was no error message from Docker daemon.

Comment: The same happens to me, using docker: Docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056
This is how I resolved:  docker tag IMAGE_ID MY_TAG

Answer (score 2):

If your Dockerfile's last line is RUN then it may hang on that during build.

I changed `RUN npm start` to `CMD ["npm", "start"]` and it's tagging now.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with Docker.

An image can have multiple tags:

```
alpine    3.4      4e38e38c8ce0        6 weeks ago         4.799 MB
alpine    latest   4e38e38c8ce0        6 weeks ago         4.799 MB
```

In this example the image with id `4e38e38c8ce0` is tagged `alpine:latest` and `alpine:3.4`. If you were to execute `docker build -t alpine .` the `latest` tag would be removed from the image `4e38e38c8ce0` and assigned to the newly built image (which has a different id).

If you remove the last `tag` from an image, the image isn't deleted automatically. It shows up as `<none>`.

Docker also uses a cache. So if you build an image with a Dockerfile, change that file, built the image again and than undo the change and build again you will have two images - the image you built in the first and last step are the same. The second image will be "tagged" `<none>`.

If you want to keep multiple version of an image use `docker build -t`<s>`tag:version`</s>`image:tag .` where <s>`version`</s>`tag` is changed every time you make some changes.

**Edit**:
What I called tag is actually the image name and what I called version is called the tag: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

Comment: the information you shared is perfectly fine but this is not what i am looking for. It is not a problem related to muliple images with same name.  thanks anyways

Comment: Than please share the output of the `docker build` command as well as `docker images`

Comment: thanks for the effort . i found out the issue and have posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

One of walkaround solution for this case, run below command immediately after build command, if all other images has already been taged.

```
docker tag $(docker image ls | grep "<none>" | awk '{print $3}') newimage:latest
```

As I know this will work only in linux os.