# Docker build command interupted, unable to tag images / Direct execution

Tags: docker, containers, tagging

I have nearly the same problem as discussed here:

[Docker build command with --tag unable to tag images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787763/docker-build-command-with-tag-unable-to-tag-images)

But I am not having an error occuring during build (as op figured out) but executing a server in the process. Last command of Dockerfile is a RUN command with a starting of a server. However, due to this, every-time I build this image, the build is never finished (it goes into the server-loop waiting for requests) and instead when stopping the container, an image with `<none>:<none>` was created.

is there any way to get this straight? Because the answer provided in the linked so-post just advises on changing the image name afterwards with a shell command.

Comment: why not to use `CMD` instead of `RUN` to start the service ?

Comment: thanks, that solved it.